# Java: Number game only showing two players

Tags: java

I have created a number guessing game. The program lets you play as many rounds as you like and in the end it is going to display the number of guesses for each round. However, my program only gives output for two players... Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Hil0 {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {   

    List<String> highscore = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList());

    while(true) {

     String namn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Välj namn");
     int a = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Mellan       0 och vilket tal vill du gissa?"));         

     int slumptal = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*a);
     int counter = 0;
     int count = 0;

     count++;
     String output = "";

     while(true) {         
     counter++;   

        String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gissa vilket tal (0-" + a +")");
        int input = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);

        if(input < slumptal) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Talet: " + input + " är för litet");      
        }
        else if(input > slumptal) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Talet: " + input + " är för stort");    
        }
        else if(input == slumptal) {
           highscore.add(namn + " " + counter + " gissningar" + " (0-" + a + ")");

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rätt!" + "\n" + 
                                               "Antal gissningar: " + 
                                               counter);                                                                                                 

           String janej = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Vill du spela igen?");

           if(janej.equalsIgnoreCase("ja")) {
              break;               
           }
           else if(janej.equalsIgnoreCase("nej")) {
              for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++) { 
              output += highscore.get(i) + "\n";
              }
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Resultat:" + "\n\n" + output);
              System.exit(0);              
           }                                                                                              
        }
      }
    }    
  }  //Main
}  //Class
```

Comment: What's your question? This is just a statement.

Comment: If you'll bother switching to English, we might understand what you're trying to do there in the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it is because you variable `count` in each loop would be equals to 1. Try to replace it in to scope out of `while loop`.

It would be looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Hil0 {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {   

    List<String> highscore = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList());
    int count = 0; // put it here instead 

    while(true) {

     String namn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Välj namn");
       int a = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Mellan       0 och vilket tal vill du gissa?"));         

     int slumptal = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*a);
     int counter = 0; 
    // int count = 0; move it out of while

     count++;
     String output = "";

     while(true) {         
     counter++;   

        String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Gissa vilket tal (0-" + a +")");
        int input = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);

        if(input < slumptal) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Talet: " + input + " är för litet");      
        }
        else if(input > slumptal) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Talet: " + input + " är för stort");    
        }
        else if(input == slumptal) {
           highscore.add(namn + " " + counter + " gissningar" + " (0-" + a + ")");

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rätt!" + "\n" + 
                                               "Antal gissningar: " + 
                                               counter);                                                                                                 

           String janej = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Vill du spela igen?");

           if(janej.equalsIgnoreCase("ja")) {
              break;               
           }
           else if(janej.equalsIgnoreCase("nej")) {
              for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) { // use < insetad of <= because you count from 0
              output += highscore.get(i) + "\n";
              }
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Resultat:" + "\n\n" + output);
              System.exit(0);              
           }                                                                                              
        }
     }
  }    
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot!!

Comment: Good Luck! Make my answer as correct answer if it helpful